# How to add product to virtuemart Cart without saving to darabase?

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

How can i add the values from my form to VM cart as product?

I have a form then when a user fill up the form the value from that form will be added to my cart for checkout? all transaction should be save to the session not in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to add extra fields to your products.

Under the products menu, there is a Custom Fields option. You can define all different kinds of fields. Simply create a field for each value you would like to collect. Then, in your product info, there is a tab for extra fields where you can add any combination of the extra fields types you have created.

Comment: what i mean is adding a product to the cart from a $_POST value is that possible

Comment: Hmm. I would still say it would be easier to add custom fields to a product, then have the customer submit that. Otherwise you will either have to write a custom form handler or use ChronoForms with some custom code using cURL to add the items to the cart as well as handle the rest of the form submission.