# joomla virtuemart customization

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Is there any possible solution to develop this http://www.tailorstore.co.uk/tailor-made-shirts
kind of functionality in joomla virtuemart like any component or module available for this attributes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is any possible solution with Joomla. Simply create a component that has the buttons and javascript to edit the image on the page you've shown there - and pass it all across into a virtuemart cart.

In terms of clicking on a button and changing the image - this is pretty basic javascript. See this [How to add product to virtuemart Cart without saving to darabase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008580/how-to-add-product-to-virtuemart-cart-without-saving-to-darabase) About adding a product into the virtuemart cart outside of virtuemart

Or use a simple shopping cart module like this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/shopping-cart/10116

In terms of an existing component changing the images like on your site the answer is no it almost certainly doesn't exist - but that's the beauty of Joomla - being able to build it easily.